# Python: Csv to kml with for loop

Tags: python, csv, kml

I am writing a script to take a csv file and write each line of the csv into a placemark in kml.  The script works up until the second for loop and it fails to write the placemarks in the kml file.  I know the script works fine up to writing the LookAt and then appears to jump over the for loop.

A little background...  The csv contains 7 columns and the last column looks like this ";latitude;longitude;radius".  That is why I have the first for loop to split out those three bits of information.

Here is what I have so far.

```
import csv
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *

root = Tk()
root.fileName = askopenfilename( filetypes = ( ("Comma Separated Values",     "*.csv"), ("All files", "*.*") ) )
print (root.fileName)
#close tkinter gui window
root.destroy()

#open the csv file
data = csv.reader(open (root.fileName), delimiter = ',')
#skip header row
next(data)

for line in data:
    raw_coordinates = line[6]
    #print raw_coordinates
    lat_long_radius = raw_coordinates.split(';')

#Open the file to be written.
f = open('TPS_Report.kml', 'w')

#Writing the kml file.
f.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n")
f.write("<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1'>\n")
f.write("<Document>\n")
f.write("   <name>" + str("TPS_Report") + '.kml' +"</name>\n") # display name of kml file in Google Earth
#Create LookAt for start location at 39,-98 4200km eye alt, 0 tilt
print ("Creating LookAt")
f.write("   <LookAt>\n")
f.write("       <longitude>" + str("-98") + "</longitude>\n")
f.write("       <latitude>" + str("39") + "</latitude>\n")
f.write("       <range>" + str("4200000") + "</range>\n")
f.write("       <tilt>" + str("0") + "</tilt>\n")
f.write("   </LookAt>\n")

for row in data:
    f.write("   <Placemark>\n")
    f.write("       <name>" + lat_long_radius[3] + " meters" + "</name>\n")
    f.write("       <description>" + str(row[0]) + "\n")
    f.write("                    " + str(row[1]) + "\n")
    f.write("                    " + str(row[2]) + "\n")
    f.write("                    " + str(row[3]) + "\n")
    f.write("                    " + str(row[4]) + "\n")
    f.write("                    " + str(row[5]) + "\n")
    f.write("                    " + str(row[6]) + "</description>\n") 
    f.write("       <gx:balloonVisibility>" + str("1") + "</gx:balloonVisibility>\n")
    f.write("       <Point>\n")
    f.write("           <coordinates>" + lat_long_radius[2] + "," + lat_long_radius[1] + "," + str(0) + "</coordinates>\n")
    f.write("       </Point>\n")
    f.write("   </Placemark>\n")

f.write("</Document>\n")
f.write("</kml>\n")
f.close()
print ("File Created. ")
print ("Press ENTER to exit. ")
raw_input()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` variable is not a list, it is an iterator that consumes your file. Once you iterate over it, you have reached the end of the file, and any attempt to iterate over it again will fail (as there is nothing more to read).

If you really need to iterate over your file twice, save the contents somewhere (in a list, for example). Or restructure your program so you do everything you need in only one pass.

Your code has also other problems, such as `lat_long_radius`, which is the same value for all points.

Comment: I figured it out.  The first loop to separate out the data needed to be  nested in the second loop.  The lat_long_radius does not have the same value for all points.  It goes through each line in the csv and pulls the data from that line.